# How can I make vim not follow links?

Tags: vim

I have a linux checkout directory with a module inside called learnldd

```
 ./linux/learnldd/hello/hello.c
```

I have a tags file called TAGS in my linux checkout

```
./linux/TAGS
```

When I open hello.c in vim, vim cannot find the tags file because learnldd is actually a link from

```
~/Repos/learnldd -> ~/Repos/linux/learnldd
```

So, when vim is searching for my tags file a la

```
:set tags=./TAGS;
```

it ends up looking in the actual directory and it's parents, rather than the linked one. If I

```
:cd ~/Repos/linux/learnldd
:pwd
```

vim follows the directory and reports that I'm in

```
cd ~/Repos/linux/learnldd
```

Is this a limitation on vim or is there some way around this without changing my link setup?

Answer (score 1):

Use the environment variable $PWD, which does not follow links. In your ~/.vimrc:

```
set tags=$PWD/TAGS;
```